# C# Handle Received data of Multiple TCP clients on TCP Server by displaying them into Datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, sockets, tcp, datagrid

I have developed a C# based TCP server GUI application which is accepting data from multiple TCP clients.

The data i am receiving from TCP clients is a 32 bit data. In my application multiple TCP client data goes like this:

00012331100025123000124510321562 (from 1 client)

01112563110002512456012451032125 and so on...

Now i want those data of the TCP clients to be parsed into 4 bits first and display it in 8 columns (32/4=8) of (say) datagrid as each 4 bit represents some characteristics of the TCP client. The same thing should work for next TCP client on second row of datagrid.

Can you give me some suggestion or an example how to go about this? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Here is my code for receiving data from multiple TCP clients.

```
void m_Terminal_MessageRecived(Socket socket, byte[] buffer)
        {
            string message = ConvertBytesToString(buffer, buffer.Length);

            PublishMessage(listMessages, string.Format("Sockets: {0}", message));

            // Send Echo
           // m_ServerTerminal.DistributeMessage(buffer);
        }


        private string ConvertBytesToString(byte[] bytes, int iRx)
        {
            char[] chars = new char[iRx + 1];
            System.Text.Decoder d = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetDecoder();
            d.GetChars(bytes, 0, iRx, chars, 0);
            string szData = new string(chars);

            return szData;
        }
```

Comment: `00012331100025123000124510321562` is more than 32 bits of information, so your description doesn't make much sense. Also, your question seems to be about displaying the information, but all you've shown is the code receiving the data. Please provide [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) showing exactly what you've tried so far, and explain precisely what that code does and how that's different from what you want it to do.

Comment: if you count that, its 32 bit of data. Dont look at those numbers. Well i asked about displaying the data, so i posted it here. If i would know then i would not have posted here. That's the code i have posted through which i am able to receive that data.

Comment: Do you know [what a bit is](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit)? Please read the link I provided in my previous comment, as well as this one too: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: Well.. Thank you for the link.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have a data grid with columns defined,first add the columns

```
for (int iIndex = 1; iIndex <= 8; iIndex++)
{
     DataColumn col = new DataGridTextColumn();
     col.Header = iIndex;
     col.Binding = new Binding(iIndex);
     YourDatagrid.Columns.Add(col);
}
```

Then after your get back the message, split the message string into 8 strings of length 4 each,create a DataItem and add it to the datagrid

```
YourDataGrid.Items.Add(new DataItem 
       { 1 = message.SubString(0,4)},
       { 2 = message.SubString(4,4)},
                   .
                   .
                   .
       { 8 = message.SubString(28,4)}
);
```

Comment: Thank you.. will go through this now.